# Java displaying images on one another and move it

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am a beginner in Java,

and i have to build a program to move a boat on a sea.

My idea is to insert an image as a background screen and then put over another image that would represent the boat.

I don't know how to make this.

How can put an image on all the Jframe as a background image, 
and how can i put over another image, and how can i move the second image on this background

Thanks.

Comment: You can use Background Panel class [Read This](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can put an image on all the Jframe as a background image,...

Avoid thinking in terms of JFrame and instead your Swing GUI work should concentrate on creating and using JPanels. This can then be displayed in a JFrame (or JDialog, or another JPanel, or...) It's easy to display a background image in a JPanel by calling `g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, null)` inside of the JPanel's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.

> and how can i put over another image, and how can i move the second image on this background

1. Simply use a 2nd BufferedImage that is drawn within the same `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, but after drawing the first image. You would use the same `g.drawImage(mySprite, x, y, null)`, but would use fields, here x and y, to change the location of the sprite image. Often the change occurs within a Swing Timer.
2. Or you could display the sprite image in an ImageIcon that is shown in a JLabel, and move the JLabel's position in your Swing Timer.

---

**Edit**  You ask:

> How can i resize a picture because when i insert it it take all of the frame?

It would probably be best to create a new BufferedImage, one the size you desire, get a Graphics object from the new image, draw the original picture into the new one using that Graphics object, and a `drawImage(...)` overload that allows for re-sizing, and then dispose of the Graphics object. For example

```
  double scale = 0.5; // make it half as wide and high as big image
  int smallImageWidth = (int) (bigImage.getWidth() * scale);
  int smallImageHeight = (int) (bigImage.getHeight() * scale);

  BufferedImage smallImage = new BufferedImage(smallImageWidth, smallImageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
  // get a Graphics object from this image
  Graphics g = smallImage.getGraphics();

  // draw in the large image, scaling it
  g.drawImage(bigImage, 0, 0, smallImageWidth, smallImageHeight, null);

  // get rid of the Graphics object to save resources
  g.dispose(); // never do this with Graphics objects given you by the JVM
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and if i succeed i validate your answer Thanks,

Comment: How can i resize a picture because when i insert it it take all of the frame?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Draggable](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/drag/Draggable.java) to make your boat draggable

```
Image background = ...;
Image boat = ...;
JPanel bgPanel = new JPanel() {
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     g.drawImage(background,0,0,null);
  }
}
JLabel boatLbl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(boat));
bgPanel.setLayout(null);
new Draggable(boatLbl);
bgPanel.add(boatLbl);
```

Comment: You should mention that Draggable is a 3rd party class, and not a Java class.